# Transactions - Oracle Vs PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

PostgreSQL do not have feature to insert Save Points in the trigger functions and when there is an exception ( Like exception NO_DATA_FOUND) the entire transaction is rolled back. But instead of rolling back the entire transaction , I just wanted to roll back to the last saved point.

Is there any other Aternative way where I can have multiple Save points within a trigger functions in Postgresql.

Here is my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_ex() RETURNS trigger AS  $func_ex$
    DECLARE               
    var_name  name;

    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO log_table (empid, empname) values (100, 'Name');

       -- savepoint my_savepoint; "cannot have savepoints in triggers

       Select empname INTO strict var_name from emp_table1 WHERE empid = 3232332;  

    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
    RAISE Notice 'No data found';
    RETURN NEW;

    END;

  return new
$func_ex$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
-- End of Function

-- Creation of Trigger
   CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger1 AFTER update of empname 
   ON emp_table1 EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_ex();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PostgreSQL do not have feature to insert Save Points in the trigger functions

Actually, it does, they're just implicit in `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` blocks.

Your code looks correct, and it's not clear what you are trying to achieve that it doesn't already do.

If you want multiple savepoints in triggers, nest `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` blocks. You can use `RAISE` with a custom `SQLSTATE` for flow control.

It'd be nice if PL/PgSQL also supported explicit named savepoints, but using exception blocks works well in my experience.

Comment: I want to prevent implicit roll back of  entire transaction when an exception is occured in the trigger functions.

Comment: @user1581721 but you already show how to do that in your question, so I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: By having Nested Begin .. Exception Blocks I could have multiple save points in the trigger functions.

Answer (score 0):

By having Nested Begin .. Exception Blocks I could have multiple save points in the trigger functions.